# Changing the codomain in the definition of the retraction map.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, retraction

In Allen Hatcher, Algebraic topology, the following paragraph exists:

> [image]

And I am wondering if in the sentence starting with "From a more formal viewpoint .....", I changed the codomain of the function $r$ to $A$ instead i.e. $r: X \rightarrow A $, how will this spoil the definition of retraction?

Thanks!

Comment: We can only compose a map with itself if it’s domain equals it’s codomain. If you want to give a general definition when the arrows are not necessarily functions, you cannot correct this by implicitly including the image in the domain.

Comment: @ConnorMalin I understood your first sentence, but I do not understand the second one.... could you please give an example? I am sorry my mother tongue is not english

Comment: If I have a function $f:X \rightarrow X$ I can talk about $f \circ f$. If I have a function $F:X \rightarrow Y$ I cannot talk about $f \circ f$ if $Y \neq X$. You might say that if $Y \subset X$ then $f \circ f$ does make sense, but technically it does not. You are implicitly writing $f \circ i \circ f$ where $i$ is the inclusion of $Y$ into $X$. The reason it is important to make this distinction is because if we are dealing with objects that aren't sets and morphisms that aren't functions, it might not make sense to talk about subobjects.

Comment: A particular reason it is good to think about a map $X \rightarrow A$ as a map $X \rightarrow X$ is because it is often important to deal with homotopies of the map that are allowed to move points inside all of $X$.

Comment: And just to be clear, this is just saying that these two concepts are different. It is actually the most common definition in general categories to define a retraction to be an arrow with a left inverse which might be where you are going.

Comment: @ConnorMalin You should give an official answer.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of giving this an answer:

If you have a function $r:X \rightarrow A$, then it does not make sense to speak of a function $r^2$; that is, $r \circ r$.

This is because the function $r$ is defined on the domain $X$, and not $A$.